# Using `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` with `styled-components`

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, eslint, styled-components

The library [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com) enable you to create custom styled components like:

```
const Button = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
`;

function App(props) {
  return (<Button onClick={() => console.log("clicked!")}>Styled</Button>);
}
```

The following button is clickable but made from a `<div />` element so `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` usually require attributes like `tabIndex`, `role`, etc.

The problem is that because the component created from `styled.div` ES-Lint can't see it. Is there a plugin or a solution for this problem?

Comment: it's an open issue https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/466

Comment: you could use other means of testing a11y like using `axe-core` for unit tests. It has a lot more rules than jsx-a11y

Answer (score 3):

I made a pretty cool plugin for this (hopefully). It found 6,567 errors in one of my repos that were undiscovered using airbnb/jsx-a11y rules. Please give it a star so we can get more people interested, using it, and contributing to make a more accessible internet for all.

Here’s the [github repo](https://github.com/brendanmorrell/eslint-plugin-styled-components-a11y) it covers all 4 styled components/emotion syntaxes

Existing a11y linting has become significantly less useful (personally, 99% of the components I need linted are styled.). Each scenario below would display the error

```
Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener.`
```

```
const Div = styled.div``;
<Div onClick={() => null}/>
```

```
const Div = styled.div.attrs({ onClick: () => null})``;
<Div />
```

```
const Div = styled.div.attrs({ onClick: () => null})``;
const StyledDiv = styled(Div)``;
<StyledDiv />
```

```
const ButtonAsDiv = styled.button``;
<ButtonAsDiv as="div" onClick={() => null} />
```

It’s not perfect (no linters are), but it’s super useful, and with a little time and community support, it could be even better.